# How can I right-align the second column in a QFormLayout?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, alignment

I have a gui from tk that I am trying to duplicate using pyqt. You can see both [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV1Mm.jpg). In the tk image, you'll notice that in the "Top 5" area, the customer name is padded with white space and the quantity shipped is aligned to the right.

I have implemented this in pyqt with a `QtGui.QFormLayout`. I have tried to `setFormAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)` however this still results in the image that you see in my link.

What am I doing wrong? [Here](http://pastebin.com/p2WBYy1M) is the entirety of my pyqt code - if you have any other suggestions on alternate, 'better' i.e. more pythonic ways of doing this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the alignment of the individual QLabels you create on line 43:

```
cust = QtGui.QLabel(' - Customer - ')
qty = QtGui.QLabel('1234')
qty.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
self.topFive.append([cust, qty])
ov_custs.addRow(cust, qty)
```

The result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPOmG.png).

I also recommend you use a QVBoxLayout as your main layout, and a QHBoxLayout to contain the "Part Number" and QLineEdit widgets. That way, you don't have to worry about grid coordinates when you add the other widgets from your tk layout:

```
vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
overviewBox = QtGui.QGroupBox('Overview')

# Main window
part_num_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
part_num_layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Part Number'))
part_num_layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLineEdit(), stretch=1)
vbox.addLayout(part_num_layout)
vbox.addWidget(overviewBox)
...
self.setLayout(vbox)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Not sure about the V/HBoxLayout vs. using Grid though. If you look at the TK layout, you'll notice I have a list on the right, akin to the `QListWidget`. In order to get this to span correctly, I'd have to have a `HBoxLayout` with a `VBoxLayout` for the widgets on the left. Then, that `VBoxLayout` would need to have another `HBoxLayout` for the part number label and entry box. So now I have layouts nested 3-deep as opposed to 2, and I just have a hard time keeping track of all that, lol.